# Find the percentage that is one integer to another

Tags: c, math

I have two integers (amount of bytes of two files). One is always smaller if not the same than the other. I want to calculate the percentage that the smaller is of the bigger.

I'm using plain C. I've applied the math formula, but am getting always 0:

```
printf("%d\r", (current/total)*100);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
printf("%g\r", (((double)current)/total)*100);
```

instead.  Integer division always rounds towards zero.  By converting one of the numbers to `double` first, you will trigger floating point division.  If you would like to use integer arithmetic, you could also use

```
printf("%d\r", (100*current)/total);
```

which will print the percentage rounded down to the next integer.

Comment: Thanks, you have an extra parenthesis in your second example ;).

Comment: where can you see an extra parenthesis ?

Comment: @Arabcoder: It's removed meanwhile.  You can see the edit history by clicking on the time after the word "edited".

Comment: what if the 100*current overflows the capacity of the type?

Answer (score 4):

Sven give you good advice.

If you want to keep your integers, do the multiplication before the division :

```
printf("%d\r", (current * 100) / total);
```

You will get a rounded result.

The integral division done with `numerator < denominator` always give 0. That's the explanation for your "always 0" problem. Multiplying by 100 before dividing get the integral part of your division (percentage)

my2c

Answer (score 2):

I recommend scaling up the nominator before doing the division:

```
const float ratio = (100.f * current) / total;
```

Here, making the 100 a floating point literal will promote the calculation, so no explicit casts are necessary which is also a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Better to try:

```
printf("%lf\r", (((double)current)/total)*100);
```

Since answer will be in floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Integer division rounds down, so if your answer is less than 1 you will get 0.

You could try something like this:

```
printf("%d\r", ((current*100)/total));
```

However you will always get an integer.

If you cast numerator to a float you will get float division and the right answer.

```
printf("%f\r", ((float)current/total * 100));
```

However you may want to truncate zeros after, for example, for 3 digits before the decimal and 2 after you can use:

```
printf("%3.2f\r", ((float)current/total * 100));
```

Check out:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/